# How to create a comment on the index.html.erb page without visits of other pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to create a comment on the `index.html.erb` page without visits of other pages (new and show). ie. I want to create comment and show it on one page (`index.html.erb`).

**Controller**

```
  def index

    @comments = Comment.all
    @users = User.all
    @count = Comment.count
    render :layout => false
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
    @coment = Comment.all
    @users = User.all
 end
  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @users = User.all
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) #whoever the logged in user is
    @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**view/_form** (it should be in `index.html.erb` page)

```
<div id="container">
  <%= form_for(@comment,:html => { class: 'niceform', :multipart =>true })  do |f| %>
      <br><br>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>new comment</legend>
        <dl>
          <dt><label for="email">Comment:</label></dt>
          <dd><%= f.text_area :text, size: "50x10" %></dd>
        </dl>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset class="action">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send comment" />
      </fieldset>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: make the form submission remote and try updating the view using create.js.erb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would want to eventually take the approach sirius ror stated in the comments which is to make a javascript call.

I will get you headed to where you can add the form to the index page.

In the controller

```
def index
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comments = Comment.all
  @users = User.all
  @count = Comment.count
  render :layout => false
end
```

In your index.html.erb file add in

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

If you then want it to work via ajax you need to update the form_for call to include :remote => true

You can then create your file "create.js.erb" and do any js stuff you need to manipulate the page

Hopefully that gets you started in the right direction